# Getting a list of points (in x, y form) in a Julia graph

Tags: plot, julia, plots.jl

If I have a Julia plot with any number of points, would it be possible for me to get a list of all of the data points within the graph (using the `Plots` library)?

EDIT: I am working with GeoStats.jl to create temporal variograms, and I just wanted to calculate the error (using RMSE and MAE) of the model's fit. To do this, I thought I had to compare the points within model's curve with the original semivariogram. The current code I have running is:

```
using GeoStats, Plots, DataFrames, CSV, Dates, MLJ

data_frame = CSV.read("C:/Users/VSCode/MINTS-Variograms/data/MINTS_001e06373996_IPS7100_2022_01_02.csv", DataFrame) 
ms = [parse(Float64,x[20:26]) for x in data_frame[!,:dateTime]]
ms = string.(round.(ms,digits = 3)*1000)
ms = chop.(ms,tail= 2)
data_frame.dateTime =  chop.(data_frame.dateTime,tail= 6)
data_frame.dateTime = data_frame.dateTime.* ms
data_frame.dateTime = DateTime.(data_frame.dateTime,"yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.sss")
ls_index = findall(x-> Millisecond(500)<x<Millisecond(1500), diff(data_frame.dateTime))
df = data_frame[ls_index, :]

#include calculation for average lag
#initialize georef data
 = georef((Z=df.pm2_5, ))

#empirical variogram - same thing as semivariogram
g = EmpiricalVariogram(, :Z, maxlag=300.)

plot(g, label = "")
γ = fit(Variogram, g)
plot!(γ, label = "")
hline!([γ.nugget], label = "")
hline!([γ.sill], label = "")

println("nugget: " * string(γ.nugget))
println("sill: " * string(γ.sill))
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here ... but to construct a plot, you need a list of all the data points. Correct? So why would you want to get a list of all of the data points from a graph (into which you presumably added the data points in the first place)? Perhaps the question needs to be clarified with an example or a code sample?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated my post with my project's intents and code snippets.

Comment: Why not compare g with fit(variogram, g) directly?

Comment: It's unclear what you are actually asking for OP. i've flagged this question for deletion. It seems like the basis of the question was a false impression you had